# How do I configure the server deploy directory in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have 2 workspaces. I can't configure the server deploy directory in the 2nd workspace.

Eclipse indigo. JBoss server 5.x.

The deploy directory is D:\Development2\projects2.metadata.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_EAP_5.x_Runtime_Server1324558380698\deploy

I want it to be D:\Development\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\default\deploy as it is for the server in the 1st workspace.

***I have tried every preference and property related to this server***, and I can't change it.  I'm all for editing an .xml file, I just can't find the one that has this information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

When you doubleclick the server name, the window that opens has TWO TABS.  Look at THE BOTTOM OF THE WINDOW.  This information is changed in that window.

Sorry for the noise. Hope this helps someone as dense as I am.

Answer (score 1):

I got this option in readonly mode.

So before making any change you have to undeploy/remove deployebles from jboss and then you can modify deployment directory operation